How to prevent Bootstrap modal from opening when clicking on link
I have a table where clicking anywhere on the row will open a modal dialog (to edit the row) but there are columns that contain links . When those links are clicked on, I don't want to go to the link and not open the modal.
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th><th>Link</th><th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr style="cursor:pointer;" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
            <td>1</td><td><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">go to google</a></td><td>2024-05-18</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content border">
            <div class="modal-header px-card bg-light border-bottom-0 p-1">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal</h5>
                <button class="btn-close me-n1" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-card">
                <p>Here's some stuff</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center bg-light">
                <button class="btn btn-primary px-4" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

I've tried stopping propagation in the onclick for the href, but it gets called after the show.bs.modal is called so doesn't help me. I can add an event listener for show.bs.modal, and was hoping to get the href element that was clicked so I could determine if it should be ignored or not, but the relatedTarget is the row, so that doesn't help me.
Am I going about this the wrong? How do I achieve the results that I'm looking for?

It's like a button inside a button, and this might be wrong design. I think it's better to have separate button for [ Edit ] - even in terms of UI/UX

Perhaps make a snippet of all your related code including the bootstrap version in use here. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You can create a modal with JavaScript instead of using data-bs-toggle="modal" and data-bs-target="#myModal" attributes.

Remove those attributes.
Add some new identifier to tr instead. Let's decide we've added data-modal-toggle="myModal". This can be used to select trigger elements and get the corresponding modal id.
Create a modal using JavaScript code and add event listener to toggle it on click.

// select all modal-trigger elements by using the proper selector
document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-toggle]').forEach((trigger) => {
  // get modal id from data-modal-toggle value
  const modalId = trigger.dataset.modalToggle;

  // create modal instance
  const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById(modalId));

  // add event listener to the modal-trigger element
  trigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // if it isn't 'a' element, then open the modal
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
      modal.toggle();
    }
  });
});

